# R: ggplot barplot for 2 groups

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization, data-visualization

```
> dput(df_male)
structure(list(Question = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("Q1", 
"Q2", "Q3", "Q4", "Q5", "Q6", "Q7", "Q8"), class = "factor"), 
    Response = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("No", 
    "Yes"), class = "factor"), Proportion = c(0.569230769230769, 
    0.569230769230769, 0.492307692307692, 0.430769230769231, 
    0.430769230769231, 0.507692307692308)), .Names = c("Question", 
"Response", "Proportion"), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 9L, 10L, 
11L), class = "data.frame")

> dput(df_female)
structure(list(Question = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("Q1", 
"Q2", "Q3", "Q4", "Q5", "Q6", "Q7", "Q8"), class = "factor"), 
    Response = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("No", 
    "Yes"), class = "factor"), Proportion = c(0.603092783505155, 
    0.65979381443299, 0.54639175257732, 0.396907216494845, 0.34020618556701, 
    0.45360824742268)), .Names = c("Question", "Response", "Proportion"
), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 9L, 10L, 11L), class = "data.frame")
```

I have 2 data frames (one for each gender) on their proportion of response to 3 questions.

```
> df_male
   Question Response Proportion
1        Q1       No  0.5692308
2        Q2       No  0.5692308
3        Q3       No  0.4923077
9        Q1      Yes  0.4307692
10       Q2      Yes  0.4307692
11       Q3      Yes  0.5076923
> df_female
   Question Response Proportion
1        Q1       No  0.6030928
2        Q2       No  0.6597938
3        Q3       No  0.5463918
9        Q1      Yes  0.3969072
10       Q2      Yes  0.3402062
11       Q3      Yes  0.4536082
```

I would like to visualize this, so I use a ggplot segmented barplot.

```
ggplot(df_male, aes(x = Question, y = Proportion)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = Response), stat = "identity") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.25)) +   # Rotate tick mark labels
  guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE)) + ggtitle("Male") + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5))

ggplot(df_female, aes(x = Question, y = Proportion)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = Response), stat = "identity") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.25)) +   # Rotate tick mark labels
  guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE)) + ggtitle("Female") + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5))
```

[image]
[image]

Is this a way to combine the 2 plots into just 1 plot? i.e. I would like to find a way to visualize proportions to these 3 questions for 2 different groups in the same plot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about stacking the data together and using an `interaction` between `gender` and `question` as your x-axis?

```
df <- rbind(cbind(df_male,gender="M"), cbind(df_female, gender = "F"))

ggplot(df, aes(x = interaction(Question,gender), y = Proportion)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = Response), stat = "identity") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.25)) +   # Rotate tick mark labels
  guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE)) + ggtitle("Male vs. Female") + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5))
```

[image]

Alternatively, I think a better solution would be to use `facet_wrap()` to group by question (or by gender if you wanted):

```
ggplot(df, aes(x =gender, y = Proportion)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = Response), stat = "identity") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.25)) +   # Rotate tick mark labels
  guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE)) + ggtitle("Male vs. Female") + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5)) + 
  facet_wrap(~Question)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Combine your data with an identifying variable and facet:

```
library(tidyverse)

bind_rows('male' = df_male, 'female' = df_female, .id = 'gender') %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = Question, y = Proportion, fill = Response)) + 
    geom_col() + 
    facet_wrap(~gender)
```

[image: facetted plot]

Edit appearance as you like. If you'd prefer a vertical layout, set `ncol = 1` in `facet_wrap`.